Payment gateway issue with WooCommerce custom order status update
I'm using custom order statusses on a few product categories on our webshop.
Now that we are live I see that all orders that are "Processing" are payed with Mollie (payment GW).
However the orders that have a custom order status, and where the customer also selected Mollie, the payment GW didn't work. The customer just gets forwarded to a next page where they see the message "Order is submitted" without the payment GW beging triggered.
The code I used:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'custom_order_status_by_cat', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_status_by_cat( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {      
      $product_id = $item->get_product_id();  
      if ( has_term( 'met-gravure', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //Categorie selecteren
         $order->update_status( 'ord-maatwerk' ); // Aangepaste status
         break;
      } else if ( has_term( 'moedermelk', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //Categorie selecteren
         $order->update_status( 'ord-moedermelk' ); // Aangepaste status
         break;
      }
else if ( has_term( 'last-minute-gepersonaliseerd-juweel', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) { //Categorie selecteren
         $order->update_status( 'ord-lastminute' ); // Aangepaste status
         break;
      }
    }
}

Find out what the code is to call the payment gateway but didn't find it.

You should not use woocommerce_checkout_order_processed hook that is triggered before the payment has been processed, for orders with Mollie payment.
Instead, for orders with Mollie payment, you should use woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status filter hook, to set the custom order statuses.
Also, to avoid an error in PHP, note that the "ELSE IF" statement doesn't include a space between else and if. Instead, simply use elseif.
Try the following, defining in the both last functions the correct Mollie payment ID:
// Utility function: Get the custom order status by product category
function get_custom_order_status_by_cat( $order, $status = false ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {      
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get product ID

        if ( has_term( 'met-gravure', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $status = 'ord-maatwerk'; // Aangepaste status
            break;
        } elseif ( has_term( 'moedermelk', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $status = 'ord-moedermelk'; // Aangepaste status
            break;
        } elseif ( has_term( 'last-minute-gepersonaliseerd-juweel', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $status = 'ord-lastminute'; // Aangepaste status
            break;
        }
    }
    return $status;
}

// For other payment gateways than Mollie
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'update_order_status_by_category', 10, 3 );
function update_order_status_by_category( $order_id, $posted_data, $order ){
    // HERE bellow, define Mollie payment method ID
    $targeted_payment_id = 'payment_id';

    $custom_status = get_custom_order_status_by_cat( $order ); // Get custom order status
    
    // If a custom order status is found and if it's NOT a Mollie payment
    if ( $custom_status && $order->get_payment_method() !== $targeted_payment_id ) { 
        $order->update_status( $custom_status );
    }
}

// For Mollie Payments
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'update_order_status_by_category_for_mollie', 10, 3 );
function update_order_status_by_category_for_mollie(  $status, $order_id, $order  ){
    // HERE bellow, define Mollie payment method ID
    $targeted_payment_id = 'payment_id';

    $custom_status = get_custom_order_status_by_cat( $order ); // Get custom order status
    
    // If a custom order status is found and if it's a Mollie payment
    if ( $custom_status && $order->get_payment_method() === $targeted_payment_id ) { 
        return $custom_status;
    }
    return $status;
}

It should work, if you set in the code the correct payment ID slug for Mollie.
Some related threads using woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status filter hook.

Thank you so much for your clear answer. Im starting to understand now (I think :-)).
If im correct the only thing I need to do is change the 'payment_id' with my Mollie ID?
Do I need to include the code "// For other payment gateways than Mollie" ? Because im not using any other payment gateway. I think it will look like this?
    // Utility function: Get the custom order status by product category
function get_custom_order_status_by_cat( $order, $status = false ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {      
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get product ID

        if ( has_term( 'met-gravure', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $status = 'ord-maatwerk'; // Aangepaste status
            break;
        } elseif ( has_term( 'moedermelk', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $status = 'ord-moedermelk'; // Aangepaste status
            break;
        } elseif ( has_term( 'last-minute-gepersonaliseerd-juweel', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            $status = 'ord-lastminute'; // Aangepaste status
            break;
        }
    }
    return $status;
}


// For Mollie Payments
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'update_order_status_by_category_for_mollie', 10, 3 );
function update_order_status_by_category_for_mollie(  $status, $order_id, $order  ){
    // HERE bellow, define Mollie payment method ID
    $targeted_payment_id = '*******';

    $custom_status = get_custom_order_status_by_cat( $order ); // Get custom order status
    
    // If a custom order status is found and if it's a Mollie payment
    if ( $custom_status && $order->get_payment_method() === $targeted_payment_id ) { 
        return $custom_status;
    }
    return $status;
}

Again thank you so much!
